# How to get rid of 'Flow sessions were not provided' exception in corda when run using network bootstrapper?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am running corda 4.5. My flows work perfectly when run using gradle task, deployNodes. But when I run the flow for the nodes created using the network bootstrapper, I run to the below exception.

```
Mon Jul 26 12:43:10 GMT 2021>>> start CreateAccount name: accountOne

▶︎ Starting
    ✘ Requesting signature by notary service
        ✘ Requesting signature by Notary service
        ✘ Validating response from Notary service
    ✘ Broadcasting transaction to participants
✘ Done
☂ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Flow sessions were not provided for the following transaction participants: [O=PartyA, L=New York, C=US]
```

From the logs:

```
inMemoryConfigSelectionLogger. - Did not detect a configuration for InMemory selection - enabling memory usage for token indexing. Please set stateSelection.inMemory.enabled to "false" to disable this 
inMemoryConfigSelectionLogger. - No indexing method specified. Indexes will be created at run-time for each invocation of selectTokens - Cordapp configuration is incorrect due to exception - empty config: No configuration setting found for key 'stateSelection'
```

Comment: please add info on the question ,if you are running through deployNodes task and it is working fine , it means your flow is ok . I am guessing your network created by bootstrapper is not correct.

Comment: This is the blog I referred - https://www.corda.net/blog/containerizing-corda-with-corda-docker-image-and-docker-compose/

Comment: We need more details here. Can you paste your code? @user16528894

Answer (score 0):

like Sneha said in the comments it's impossible to be confident about the source of the issues here without more context about the code here.

Remember that you want to be sure flow sessions are provided in a way similar to this where you specify the identities in a list and submit them to finality flow.

```java
        Party me = getOurIdentity();
        Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);
        Command<YoContract.Commands.Send> command = new Command<YoContract.Commands.Send>(new YoContract.Commands.Send(), Arrays.asList(me.getOwningKey()));
        YoState state = new YoState(me, this.target);
        StateAndContract stateAndContract = new StateAndContract(state, YoContract.ID);
        TransactionBuilder utx = new TransactionBuilder(notary).withItems(stateAndContract, command);

        this.progressTracker.setCurrentStep(VERIFYING);
        utx.verify(getServiceHub());

        this.progressTracker.setCurrentStep(SIGNING);
        SignedTransaction stx = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(utx);

        this.progressTracker.setCurrentStep(FINALISING);
        FlowSession targetSession = initiateFlow(this.target);
        return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(stx, Collections.singletonList(targetSession), Objects.requireNonNull(FINALISING.childProgressTracker())));
    }
```

source: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Features/dockerform-yocordapp/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/dockerform/flows/YoFlow.java